# Custom Product Collection not Getting Filtered by Layered Navigation

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation

I had Overridden the product List.php Class & here is the code

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{   
 if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {

$result = array_unique($productIds);        

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);
$collection->addIdFilter($result);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);

$this->_productCollection = $collection;
}

return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

working fine, I also had added Layered Navigation as mentioned here and layered navigation appeared as expected.

The only problem is, when I click on any filter in layered navigation, navigation gets updated and filter also get added to url, but product list won't get filtered by the selected filter. Please guide me how can I apply the filters on product collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For layered Navigation you have to:

Extend

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php

to your custom module.

And over ride prepare collection function:

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection){
    if(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
        return parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);
    else{
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
            $collection->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Check this Reference [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503447/magento-how-to-add-layered-navigation-to-advanced-search)

Comment: Let's say I have a widget with a custom product colleciton -- how can I use the above function?

Comment: Hi TBI Infotech, im facing exactly the same issue in magento 2.0... i have overridden LayeredNavigation (Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation) class, but as above problem, filters come in URL, but they are not getting applied....I have also overridden Magentos Catalog's Block Product ListProduct's  _getProductCollection().

Comment: I have updated the issue with code in Magento 2 here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138474/magento-2-custom-product-collection-not-getting-filtered-by-layered-navigation

Comment: What is the equivalent class in Magento2 for app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer...?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{   
  if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
    $result = array_unique($productIds);        
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $result));
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

So try the above code let me know if any comments.

Comment: `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $result));` made no difference, same result

Comment: Collection is filtering just fine, but the selected filter of layered navigation is not getting applied on him

Comment: then you have to check filter file i think layer.php

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong, but I think Layer.php is not responsible for filtering the product collection but it creates a layered navigation based on the product collection which it gets from the current category

Comment: public function getProductCollection()
{ 
if(isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
 $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
} else {
$collection = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection(); $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
}
 return $collection;
    }

Comment: yes filters are loading as per product attributes

Comment: Hi @Keyul, can u suggest the solution for the same issue in Magento 2, i have update the code here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138474/magento-2-custom-product-collection-not-getting-filtered-by-layered-navigation