# Search current store products only

Tags: catalog, frontend, catalogsearch, search

I am working on one website multiple stores.My issue is when i search from frontend with one store then other store products also coming.

Answer (score 1):

For the Sports Store you have to disable all music products from product grid and for the music store you have to disable all sports products. you can do it from product Grid.

```
Admin > Catalog > Manage Products
```

Choose Store View : Sports Store And select All Music Store Products if there and from mass action select Change Status to Disable.

Choose Store View : Music store And select All Sports Store Products if there and from mass action select Change Status to Disable.

Once all done do the Re-Indexing for all.

Comment: How can i do programatically?

Comment: You want to display in site right?? I guess, that s enough. No need of programming.

Comment: Yes i want in front end, but I want programatically because if i have multiple stores then i have to change visible status for all stores.

Comment: I google and find this place where i apply category filter for collection, [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/custom-product-collection-not-getting-filtered-by-layered-navigation],but this is not working for me in this function prepareProductCollection.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. So far I am able to do this at the website level but not at the store level.

You might want to try out the visibility option which is at the store view level:

This is only in theory, I have not tested.
For e.g.

Product A and Product B
Store A and Store B

Configuration is:

Store A -> Product A [Visibility: Catalog, Search]

Store B -> Product A [Visibility: Not Visible Individually]

Store A -> Product B [Visibility: Not Visible Individually]

Store B -> Product B [Visibility: Catalog, Search]