# Magento 2 - Custom Product Collection not Getting Filtered by Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2

Need suggestion on this!

I have overridden Magentos Catalog's Block Product ListProduct's  `_getProductCollection()`

So when i search for a keyword in home page, my custom blocks `_getProductCollection()` should be called.

[Custom Product Collection not Getting Filtered by Layered Navigation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/custom-product-collection-not-getting-filtered-by-layered-navigation)

**Vendor\Catalog\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
</config>
```

**\Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
     CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,

    \Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
    $this->catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory = $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory;
    $this->catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

    parent::__construct($context,$postDataHelper,$layerResolver,$categoryRepository,$urlHelper,$data);
  }

 public function _getProductCollection()
{
    echo ' Tagcataloggetproc colle';
    //problem here...this fun not at all getting called!
}
```

**\Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ToolbarModel;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public function __construct(
    /* passing all Constructors parameters to the parent class -Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php*/
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    ToolbarModel $toolbarModel,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    ProductList $productListHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    //\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    //\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper, 
    array $data = []
)  {
        $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        $this->_toolbarModel = $toolbarModel;
        $this->_urlEncoder = $urlEncoder;
        $this->_productListHelper = $productListHelper;
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
        //$this->_registry = $registry;
        //$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$catalogConfig,$toolbarModel,$urlEncoder,$productListHelper,$postDataHelper,$data);
   }

   //Overriden methods below:
  getAvailableOrders()

 getOrderDirection($sort_id)

setDefaultOrder($field) 

isOrderCurrent($key) 

}
```

**\Vendor\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product;

class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{

   protected $tglssearchHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
    \Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null
) {
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $eavConfig,
        $resource,
        $eavEntityFactory,
        $resourceHelper,
        $universalFactory,
        $storeManager,
        $moduleManager,
        $catalogProductFlatState,
        $scopeConfig,
        $productOptionFactory,
        $catalogUrl,
        $localeDate,
        $customerSession,
        $dateTime,
        $groupManagement,
        $connection
    );
}

    //    my custom methods()...
```

**Now Overriding LayeredNavigation**

**\Vendor\LayeredNavigation\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" />
</config>
```

in **Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation.php**

Have **_prepareLayout()** as is from core and overridden **canShowBlock()**

Now,

1) Why is the custom product collections not coming from ListProduct()?

2) collection not getting filtered by Layered Navigation?

Please suggest where is the issue in collection!

Comment: Have you find the solution for it? If so, please share your answer

Comment: No..only in my Catalog product its gets filtered, but when i search for a product, my custom product still not loads...

Comment: Got the solution? @NalinSavaliya

Comment: @YasarArafath I did it 2 year back, you may get solution from it. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142562/how-to-update-category-page-with-custom-filters-and-also-layered-navigation-ma