# Modify product collection in M2

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, collection, overrides

I am overriding `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`
In function `_getProductCollection` I have added some extra code.

```
public function _getProductCollection()
{ 
 $collection = parent::_getProductCollection(); 
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute', array('operator' =>
        'value')) 
    return $collection  
}
```

But my collection in not attaching this attribute. I am getting only default collection except adding `operator` attribute

Any idea ??

Comment: Instead of  `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute', array('operator' =>
        'value'))`
try this  `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('operator', 'value')`

Comment: How are you overriding the method? Using a preference?
Perhaps you should try using a plugin, something like `public function afterGetLoadedProductCollection()` which only calls the protected function you're trying to override and returns a collection instance. Then you can try adding the attribute you need.
Furthermore check the attribute settings. It must be used in product listing.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your method should be compatible with the original method. So you should make it `protected` instead of `public`.

Now the problem.. 
The original `_getProductCollection` calls `initializeProductCollection` from the same class.
This method dispatches an event that can be used to alter the collection.

```
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
        ['collection' => $collection]
    );
```

So far so good.
Now the real problem.
There is an observer that hooks into this event.
In the review module in `frontend/events.xml` there is this:

```
<event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
    <observer name="review" instance="Magento\Review\Observer\CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver" shared="false" />
</event>
```

and the observer method looks like this:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    if ($productCollection instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
        $productCollection->load();
        $this->_reviewFactory->create()->appendSummary($productCollection);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, there is this line `$productCollection->load();`.
This actually executes the sql query from the collection and loads the products from the db.
Any other modifications you add to the collection after `load` is called (or after the collection gets iterated) is useless. It will not affect the collection in any way.

Possible solutions:

1. Create a `before` plugin for the `Magento\Review\Observer\CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver::execute` method and attach your filter to the collection.  But this is not really that clean and it doesn't insure that there will be no other events that do the same. This would only work if the observer mentioned above is run before any other observer that might call `load` on the collection.  If you don't have such modules, you should be safe, but if you install one in the future it might take a lot of time to identify the problem.
2. Create an `after` on the method `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer::getProductCollection` that gets executed inside the method you are changing. But this may (or may not) have side effects and change the collection in other places.
3. There may be other solutions that I don't know of.

Comment: I am not quite sure if we can create plugin for Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer

Comment: technically or business wise? Technically is possible.

Comment: whats the best solution for this?

Comment: I don't know. I would go with the plugin on the layer model. but I would check for side effects. I don't know where to tell you to look because I don't know the business case.

Comment: I created obsever on catalog_block_product_list_collection event and good part is that works

Comment: ah...you're lucky that your observer runs first.

Comment: i used catalog_block_product_list_collection observer but $collection->getsize() wrong count in toolbar and layernavigation.

Answer (score 1):

I created observer for `catalog_block_product_list_collection` and added my filter there and am able to get the desired products

Answer (score 1):

For overriding `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` In function `_getProductCollection`. Create observer for `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event in custom module.

Create `events.xml` in the module `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml` there is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- event catalog_product_collection_load_after -->
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="product_collection_available" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductCollectionObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and the observer method `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ProductCollectionObserver.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * ProductCollectionObserver
 */
class ProductCollectionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Handler for load product collection event
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /* set your filter here */
        $observer->getEvent()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', ['operator' => 'value']);
        /* attribute_code (custom or default both are work) */
        /* If multiselect type attribute use finset as showing below */
//            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', ['finset' => [$attrOptionId]]); $attrOptionId like (1,2,3)
    
       return $this;
    }
}
```

`Thank You!`

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh. Can you please let me know how can I achieve the same for Search page results? I want to apply same filter on search page results. TIA :)

Comment: @AhsanHorani `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event works for me with search page results as well. But it won't update pagination block and layered navigation in category page so please check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142562/how-to-update-category-page-with-custom-filters-and-also-layered-navigation-ma/352802#352802. You can use some other event to check `catalog_product_load_after` or `catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after`. Thank You!

Comment: I use above code but its giving error while finding a sku ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('test')); " SELECT ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2) AS `min_price_expr` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` 
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id WHERE (((e.sku= 'test')))