# Wrong number of result in toolbar after overriding ListProduct

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, toolbar

I've overrided the **ListProduct.php** file for the catalog, to show product based on customer attribute.

But now I have the wrong number of element in the toolbar (I have 3 products displayed but still the "unfiltered" number in the toolbar).

I've added condition in **initializeProductCollection** function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answser :

Best solution seems to be to override IndexBuilder  **Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search**

see : [How to update category page with custom filters, and also layered navigation, Magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142562/how-to-update-category-page-with-custom-filters-and-also-layered-navigation-ma)