# How to add attribute filter in product listing page in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, filter

How to add attribute filter.For eg, When city attribute not set in any product then this product are showing after filter of city.

Here is my Product Collection List.php block file

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }
protected function _getProductCollection()
        {

            if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
                $layer = $this->getLayer();
                /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
                if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                    $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
                }

                // if this is a product view page
                if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                    // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                    $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                        ->setPage(1, 1)
                        ->load();
                    // if the product is associated with any category
                    if ($categories->count()) {
                        // show products from this category
                        $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                    }
                }

                $origCategory = null;
                if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                    if ($category->getId()) {
                        $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                        $this->addModelTags($category);
                    }
                }

                $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection(); //-old

                $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

                if ($origCategory) {
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
                }           
            }


            return $this->_productCollection;
        }
```

Load collection file - list.phtml

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'ASC')->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=> 'city','null' => true),
        array('attribute'=> 'city','eq' => ''),
        array('attribute'=> 'city','eq' => 'NO FIELD')),
    '',
    'left');
```

check below link.
https://vidyutbazar.com/product-services/guntur
showing only set guntur city product not showing not set city product.
But i am not able to showing correct result.Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add attrbiute filters on product collection like following. Hope it works.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()   
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')                 
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('notnull' => true))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date',array(array('lteq' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()),
                        array('special_from_date', 'null'=>true)))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date',array(array('gteq' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()),
                        array('special_to_date', 'null'=>true)))
                        ->addWebsiteFilter($wesiteid);
```

Comment: in which file add code

Comment: Add your code in /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php file's getProductCollection function.

Comment: when add your code showing empty product  . plz check below my function code .   public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection();
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }return $collection;  }

Comment: Hi. Try this code: $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('city',array(array('eq' => true),array('city', 'null'=>true)));

Comment: You can check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/custom-product-collection-not-getting-filtered-by-layered-navigation for more information.

Comment: this is not work for me